# Using tikz-cd the labels are not centered and arrows done not come together

Tags: tikz-cd

Using tikz with tikzcd the:

- label on the arrow are not centered, see those that sloped.
- When arrow split ans come back together the distance between the end points are not equal.

How do you solve these?

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=large, row sep=large]
    &&\arrow[rr,"decrement"]&& 
    \arrow[rd,sloped, midway,"return"]&&\\

    \text{Start}\arrow[r,"f(x)"]&
    \ \arrow[ur,"x > 0",sloped,description]\arrow[rd,"x\leq0",sloped,above]
    &&&\    &\arrow[r]&\text{End}\\

    &&\arrow[rr,"increment"]    && \arrow[sloped]{ru}{return}&&
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

The output is:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but labels on sloped arrows seem to be anchored at the arrow's center with one of their borders.

You can manually move the label along the arrow, but for this particular case there si s slicker trick, that also allows to easily avoid the wrong typesetting of labels with math italic.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\ctext}[1]{\text{\makebox[0pt]{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=large, row sep=large]
  && \arrow[rr,"\ctext{decrement}"]
  && \arrow[rd,sloped, midway,"\ctext{return}"]
  &&
\\
  \text{Start}\arrow[r,"f(x)"]
  & \arrow[ur,"\ctext{$x > 0$}",sloped,description]
    \arrow[rd,"\ctext{$x\leq0$}",sloped,above]
  &&&&
  \arrow[r]
  &\text{End}
\\
  && \arrow[rr,"\ctext{increment}"]
  && \arrow[ru,sloped,"\ctext{return}"]
  &&
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: slicker trick :-); where the the 'return' arrows come together the one looks longer than the other, can any thing be done about it?

Comment: @Johan `\arrow[rd,"\ctext{$x\leq0$}",sloped,above, start anchor=center, shorten <= .5em]`

Comment: @Johan or add an `\vphantom{X}` to any cell you want to leave free.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=large, row sep=large]
&&\arrow[rr,"decrement"]&& \arrow[rd,sloped, midway,"return"]&&\\
\text{Start}\arrow[r,"f(x)"]&\ \arrow[ur,sloped,description,"x > 0"near end]\arrow[rd,"x\leq0"near start,sloped,above]&&&\    &\arrow[r]&\text{End}\\
&&\arrow[rr,"increment"]    && \arrow[sloped]{ru}{return}&&
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Here is the code with the modification.

```
    \documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=large, row sep=large]
&&\arrow[rr,"decrement"]&& \arrow[rd,sloped, midway,"return"near start]&&\\
\text{Start}\arrow[r,"f(x)"]&\ \arrow[ur,sloped,description,"x > 0 "near end]\arrow[rd,"x\leq0"near start,sloped,above]&&&\    &\arrow[r]&\text{End}\\
&&\arrow[rr,"increment"]    && \arrow[ru,sloped, midway,"return"near end]&&
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Almost perfect, you forgot to center the "return" text