# Overlapping arrow and twisted labels in tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-cd

The tikz-cd code

```
\documentclass[standalone]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}

\newcommand{\ctext}[1]{\text{\makebox[0pt]{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[![enter image description here][1]][1]
\begin{tikzcd}
&&\sigma_{0}\arrow[r]&\vphantom{X} \\
\sigma_{init}\arrow[rru,"\ctext{cdsa\_in(1)}",sloped, start anchor=center,shorten <= .5em]\arrow[rrd,"\ctext{cdsa\_in(n)}", rotate=-1.25, sloped,start anchor=center, shorten <= .5em]&&& \\
&&\vphantom{X}\sigma_{n}\arrow[r]&\vphantom{X} \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

creates the diagram

[image]

The use of the macro `\ctext` etc solve a [problem  of centering the labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/456832/using-tikz-cd-the-labels-are-not-centered-and-arrows-done-not-come-together/456835#456835) and the key word `rotate` is used to better align `cdsa_in` with it's arrow.

- does an alternative exist that better align labeled with the associated arrow?
- The arrow is over the subscript `init` how can this be solved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're complicating your life.

Here a simpler code: `nodes in empty cells` allows to avoid phantoms, `&[16pt]` add some space between the first two columns, no need to create an empty one.

Off-topic: a `figure` environment in a `standalone` document has no sense.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}

\newcommand{\ctext}[1]{\text{\makebox[0pt]{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[nodes in empty cells]
&[16pt] \sigma_{0}\arrow[r]& \\
\sigma_{init}\arrow[ru,"\ctext{cdsa\_in(1)}", sloped]\arrow[rd,"\ctext{cdsa\_in(n)}", swap, sloped]&& \\
&\sigma_{n}\arrow[r]&
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for your initial comment :-).